# How to add MBProgressHUD waiting loading data in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, mbprogresshud

I have a problem: I used AFNetworking to get data from server, i used NSOperationQueue to add many operation to it, in each request, I added this operation to queue and used `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` as bellow :

```
request 1
...
    [queue addOperation:operation1];
    [queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];

request 2
...
    [queue addOperation:operation2];
    [queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
```

I tried above code and my programs seems hangs and after that, it runs ok.So that I want to added MBProgressHUD to waiting queue finish, then I want to check if queue finish, I want to hide MBProgressHUD. But when i click on Button to load UIViewController, MBProgressHUD cannot show.

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
[self.view addSubview:HUD];
HUD.delegate = self;
HUD.labelText = @"Loading";
```

Actually, I want to show MBProgressHUD when queue finish. How can i do that? Thanks all

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shortly you can do it like this:

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Check `MBProgressHUD`'s [usage](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD#usage)

Answer (score 3):

**Another Better Approach..**

```
  HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    HUD.labelText = @"Doing funky stuff...";
    HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Just relax";
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];

    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(doSomeFunkyStuff) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

And doSomeFunkyStuff

```
- (void)doSomeFunkyStuff {
    float progress = 0.0;

    while (progress < 1.0) {
        progress += 0.01;
        HUD.progress = progress;
        usleep(50000);
    }
}
```

Detail **[answer is here..](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-uiactivityindicatorview-and-mbprogresshud--mobile-10530)**

Answer (score 2):

`waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` will bock the current thread, which is probably the main thread so you really don't want to do that.

If you're using AFNetworking then check out this method on `AFHTTPClient`

```
- (void)enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:(NSArray *)operations 
                              progressBlock:(void (^)(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations))progressBlock 
                            completionBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *operations))completionBlock;
```

So show you HUD then call this method and hide your HUD in the `completionBlock`